Как изменить скорость изменения картинок бэкграунда?
Я делаю простую анимацию бэкграунда.

...и у меня получается очень длинным время перехода между картинками. общее время анимации - 100 секунд. как быть? как сократить время перехода? возможно ли это при помощи css?
спор с модератором: что значит вопрос не по теме.??? простой вопрос по css. ничего лишнего.

Текст должен быть текстом, а не картинкой

«что значит вопрос не по теме.???» — это значит то, что вместо минимального воспроизводимого примера вы вбросили скриншот огрызка стилей, что в таком виде нарушает правила сайта

если вы не разбираетесь в коде зачем вы вообще пишите комментарий?....

Мы разбираемся в коде. Мы не разбираемся и не должны разбираться в картинках

Если я не ошибаюсь, то у Вас
.block_1__body{
  /* --- */
  animation: photo 100s infinite;
  /* --- */
}

100s это как раз таки длительность всей анимации, измените данный параметр на тот который для вас более приемлемый.

Если вы хотите сократить переход между картинок, уберите transition(он в принципе тут не работает) и задайте чёткие диапазоны анимации. Пример:
@keyframes photo{
  100%,0%,23%{
    background-image: ...
  }
  25%, 48%{
    background-image: ...
  }
  50%, 73%{
    background-image: ...
  }
  75%, 98%{
    background-image: ...
  }
}

